# Putty password as root or any user access denied

Tags: putty, root

I try to log in with PuTTY as root or normal users and recive the error access denied.

[Access deined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjqU1.png)

[sshd_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wYB1.png)

putty ok
user name ok (i've tested root and non-root users)
password ok (i've used it on linux machine login in root and its ok)
sshd_config ok

so what can I do?

Comment: Do not post text as images. Please replace the images in your post with their text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `#` before `PermitRootLogin Yes`.

`#` means the line becomes a comment and is ignored by sshd.

Note that this is a security issue.

You should use public/private keys to login. This is worth setting up from a security POV.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I rewrote it in what I think is easier to understand English.  I hope I retained the intended meaning.

Comment: i've tryed remove # and nothing changes

Comment: @gvimieiro You need also to restart sshd service after change.

Comment: I've restarted service and so and nothing changes

Comment: @gvimieiro Now you should be able to login with root credentials. If it is not working then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: now i can access simple users but not with root.

Comment: @gvimieiro Please share in the question the whole file: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - remove all lines starting with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

## This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See

## sshd_config(5) for more information.

## This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

## The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with

## OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where

## possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the

## default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

## Ciphers and keying

#RekeyLimit default none

## Logging

#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

## Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

## Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.

#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

## For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

#HostbasedAuthentication no

## Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for

## HostbasedAuthentication

#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no

## Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files

#IgnoreRhosts yes

## To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!

#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

## Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with

## some PAM modules and threads)

KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

## Kerberos options

#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

## GSSAPI options

#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

## Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,

## and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will

## be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and

## PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,

## PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass

## the setting of "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password".

## If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without

## PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication

## and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.

UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

## no default banner path

#Banner none

## Allow client to pass locale environment variables

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

## override default of no subsystems

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

## Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis

#Match User anoncvs

## X11Forwarding no

## AllowTcpForwarding no

## PermitTTY no

## ForceCommand cvs server

Comment: Hi, this is unreadable.  Would you please normal sized font and dont bold anything.  This looks like an attack on the visual senses.